# zend 1.12 $form->isValid always true

Tags: forms, zend-framework

this line always return true even if username input is empty

`if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {`

my form username input looks like this

```
<?php
$this->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username'));
$this->addElement('text','username',
                 array('class' => 'input-large',
                 'value' => $this->user_login,
                 'attribs'    => array('disabled' => 'disabled') /// it can be activated by button in view
));

    $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
    $username->addValidator ( new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty() );
?>
```

but something like this works

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
          $data = $_POST['username'];
          if($validator->isValid($data)) {

            echo 'sweet';

          }else {

            echo 'bad';
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the element to be required instead of adding a validator:

```
$this->addElement('text','username', array(
    'class' => 'input-large',
    'value' => $this->user_login,
    'attribs' => array('disabled' => 'disabled'),
    'required' => true
));
```

The reason is that form elements have an 'allow empty' flag that's enabled by default, and with this flag on, your validator won't be used. I explained why this is the case in this question: [Zend Framework notEmpty validator setRequired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701072/zend-framework-notempty-validator-setrequired) . Setting the required flag instead automatically adds a `NotEmpty` validator and changes the flag.

Comment: Hey,after adding your line it started to work

but now i added some new validators like Alnum and EmailAddress 

Then i wrote in input text like 'asasdasdasd' and isValid return true

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you're using now?

Comment: that was my bad,everything is working fine with your fix 

thx very much!